# Magento migration from 1.9 to 2.0 with sample data

Tags: magento-1.9, migration, magento-2.0.2, magento2-migration-tool

I am trying to migrate magento 1.9.2.3 to 2.0.2. Initially i have tried with few of my products and orders in magento 1.9. It is migrated successfully (data with simple product, one order, one customer and settings).

When i tried to migrate to 2.0.2 with sample data installed in 1.9.2.3, i got this error:
`[Migration\Exception] 
Integrity Check failed 
migrate:data [-r|--reset] config`

How to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this migration by using [this tool](https://github.com/ubertheme/magento2_data_migration/releases).

This tool migrates all data like customer, catalog-categories and products, orders and all other data in magento 1.x.x to 2.0.x by simply specifying necessary data like Server and DB Details.
You can check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jvr8d3OeB8M&feature=youtu.be).

Eventhough This tool migrates some data, we have to manually migrate these data [check here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-manually.html).